# Server socket application turns into infinite loop when trying to break the "receive" loop in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I've made a chat server in Python 3. It establishes a connection with a client, waits for a message from the client, prints the message and saves the message to a txt file. When the client sends the message b'/dc', the client closes the connection and the server should break the loop. Instead, the client closes fine, but the server loop infinitely prints an empty message to the screen.

Server:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
import optparse

def createServer(port):

    # create a TCP socket
    sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind the socket to the port
    server_address = ('localhost', port)
    print("starting up on {} port {}".format(*server_address))
    sck.bind(server_address)

    # put the socket into server mode
    sck.listen(5)

    return sck


def runServer(sck, conn, client, logs):

    # server loop
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data != b'/dc':
            message = client[0] + ': ' + data.decode() + '\n'
            print(message)
            logs.write(message)
        else:
            conn.close()
            break


def main():

    # option to set port when launching the server
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("Usage: pyhon3 server.py -p <server port>")
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='port', type='int', help="specify target port")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    port = options.port

    if port == None:
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)

    # create server logs
    logs = open('./logs.txt', 'a+')

    # create the socket
    sck = createServer(port)


    # wait for connection and start thread
    conn, client = sck.accept()
    runServer(sck, conn, client, logs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.connect(server_address)

while True:

    # Send data
    message = bytes(input('> '), 'utf8')
    if message != b'/dc':
        print('sending {!r}'.format(message))
        sock.sendall(message)
    else:
        break

sock.close()
```

Client output:

```
connecting to localhost port 10000
> test
sending b'test'
> 123
sending b'123'
> /dc
```

Server output:

```
127.0.0.1: test

127.0.0.1: 123

127.0.0.1: 

127.0.0.1: 

127.0.0.1: 

127.0.0.1: 

127.0.0.1: 
...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code you show is not the code you are running. The code you show will exit whenever the client will send something else than `/dc` (writes message only if  `data == b'/dc'`) and the client will never send `/dc` (exits on `/dc` and does not send it to the server). This is not only from code analysis but from actually running the code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You're right, I edited it. The edited code does run the infintie loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     if data != b'/dc':
>         message = client[0] + ': ' + data.decode() + '\n'
>         print(message)
>         logs.write(message)
>     else:
>         conn.close()
>         break
> ```

This expects the client to send `/dc` in order to exit the loop. But the client will never send `/dc` because it will exit the loop and close the socket when `/dc` was entered and will not send the `/dc` before socket close:

> ```
> if message != b'/dc':
>     print('sending {!r}'.format(message))
>     sock.sendall(message)
> else:
>     break
> ```

In case of close in the client the server will `recv` and empty string. And an empty string is `!= b'/dc'` which means it matches the condition to print the message and not to close the connection and exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

In your server loops, under if statement, you print the message when it gets b'/dc' but you never close the connection. There should be a conn.close() statement at the end of the if segment. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for commenting! But I made a mistake. The if statement is supposed to say "if data != b'/dc':" instead. I'll edit it. It's supposed to close if the server receives b'/dc', hence the else, which closes the connection and breaks the loop (in theory, which it doesn't, hence my infinite loop problem).

Comment: Yes that makes more sense yes. I was wondering why you needed both the if statement and else statement to close the connection.